# Should I mention two activity tags for two classes in Manifest file?

Tags: android

I am having two classes in my android project so, should I mention two activity tags in my app manifest file or will it work without including the activity tag.

Although, my app is working fine but I think this creates error - Unfortunately, your app has stopped working.

Comment: `having two classes in my android project so, should I mention two activity tags in my app manifest` Only if these Classes are Activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends Which kind of classes you have.. if your class is extending `Activity`or `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` or the class wich extends any of these, than you must define it in `manifests.xml` file. otherwise if your class extends nothing or just extends view, then no need to define it in `manifests.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,every `Activity` you used must be declared in `manifests.xml`,or when jump the activity,app will crash.